# Why when the character is climbing stairs in the middle if stopping moving the character he is slowly moving down back the stairs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The character(player) have Capsule Collider , Rigid body , Character Controller.
a screenshot of the character(player) inspector settings :

[image: Character settings]

This is the script Character Controller :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float jumpForce = 2.0f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        float translatioin = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
        float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
        translatioin *= Time.deltaTime;
        straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translatioin);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }

        transform.Translate(0, jumpForce * Input.GetAxis("Jump") * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Then there is a Main Camera child of the player :
screenshot of the camera inspector :

[image: Camera inspector]

The script Drag Rigidbody that make object to be able to be dragged :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    public class DragRigidbody : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool useMouseHoldDown = true;

        [SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

        const float k_Spring = 50.0f;
        const float k_Damper = 5.0f;
        const float k_Drag = 10.0f;
        const float k_AngularDrag = 5.0f;
        const float k_Distance = 0.2f;
        const bool k_AttachToCenterOfMass = false;

        private SpringJoint m_SpringJoint;
        private bool isDragging;

        private void Awake()
        {
            if (!mainCamera) mainCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();
            if (!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || isDragging) return;

            // Make sure the user pressed the mouse down
            if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                return;
            }

            // We need to actually hit an object
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            if (
                !Physics.Raycast(mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition).origin,
                                 mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition).direction, out hit, 100,
                                 Physics.DefaultRaycastLayers))
            {
                return;
            }
            // We need to hit a rigidbody that is not kinematic
            if (!hit.rigidbody || hit.rigidbody.isKinematic)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!m_SpringJoint)
            {
                var go = new GameObject("Rigidbody dragger");
                Rigidbody body = go.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
                m_SpringJoint = go.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
                body.isKinematic = true;
            }

            m_SpringJoint.transform.position = hit.point;
            m_SpringJoint.anchor = Vector3.zero;

            m_SpringJoint.spring = k_Spring;
            m_SpringJoint.damper = k_Damper;
            m_SpringJoint.maxDistance = k_Distance;
            m_SpringJoint.connectedBody = hit.rigidbody;

            StartCoroutine("DragObject", hit.distance);
        }


        private IEnumerator DragObject(float distance)
        {
            isDragging = true;

            var oldDrag = m_SpringJoint.connectedBody.drag;
            var oldAngularDrag = m_SpringJoint.connectedBody.angularDrag;
            m_SpringJoint.connectedBody.drag = k_Drag;
            m_SpringJoint.connectedBody.angularDrag = k_AngularDrag;

            if (useMouseHoldDown == true)
            {
                while (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                {
                    var ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                    m_SpringJoint.transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance);
                    yield return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                while (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                {
                    var ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                    m_SpringJoint.transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance);
                    yield return null;
                }
            }
            if (m_SpringJoint.connectedBody)
            {
                m_SpringJoint.connectedBody.drag = oldDrag;
                m_SpringJoint.connectedBody.angularDrag = oldAngularDrag;
                m_SpringJoint.connectedBody = null;
            }

            isDragging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the screenshot some scripts disabled just for testing but even then the player is moving down the stairs if not keeping moving him up with the W key. The player is not falling but moving down back the stairs when releasing the W key.

It's also making problem when dragging an object for example 3d cube if I  drag the cube and then move the mouse cursor too fast around it will push the player hard to some direction until the player will stop slowly. I guess the problem is something with the rigidbody on the FPSController but not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation: *The Coroutines should do yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate(), because physics should be run in the FixedUpdate() loop.*